# matching 2 out of 3 (or excluding one) in MongoDb aggregation

Tags: mongodb

Let's say I have a mongo db restaurant collection that has an array of different foods, and I want to average the price of the "sandwich" and the "burger" for each restaurant i.e. to not include the steak. How do I match 2 out of the 3 types in this situation i.e. or, in other words, filter out the steak?

For example, for the match operator, I can (assuming I have already unwound the array) do something like this

```
{ $match : { foods : "burger" } }
```

but I want to do something more like this (which leaves out steak)

```
   { $match : { foods : ["burger", "sandwich" ]} }
```

except that code doesn't work.

Can you explain?

```
"_id" : ObjectId("50b59cd75bed76f46522c34e"),
"restaurant_id" : 0,
"foods" : [

    {
        "type" : "sandwich",
        "price" : 6.99
    },
    {
        "type" : "burger",
        "price" : 5.99
    },
    {
        "type" : "steak"
        "price" : 9.99
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`$in`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/in/#op._S_in) to match one of multiple values:

```js
{ $match : { foods : { $in: ["burger", "sandwich" ]}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

JohnyHK's answer is right and concise.

For the "Can you explain?" part, when you specified the match as follows:

{ $match : { foods : ["burger", "sandwich" ]} }

You are requiring the document to have a field "foods" containing an array with "burger" and "sandwich" as elements.  This is an equals comparison.

The operator $in is not directly explained with the $match, see here:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/match/

since $in is a query operator, which is explained here (linked from $match):
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#read-operations-query-argument